# Can't set md-select default text using (the value is set, but the text isn`t)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

This must be a very easy thing to do, but I just can't figure it out.

My code works like a charm when I use `<select>` and even when I use `<md-select>`, but `<md-select>` only works with static options.

Component:

```
this.clientService.getClients()
    .subscribe(
        items => {
            this.clients = items;
    });
```

This code works:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="item.client" name="item.client">
    <option *ngFor="let client of clients" value="{{client.$key}}">
        {{client.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

This code DOES NOT work:

```
<md-select [(ngModel)]="item.client" name="item.client">
    <md-option *ngFor="let client of clients" value="{{client.$key}}">
        {{client.name}}
    </md-option>
</md-select>
```

This code DOES work:

```
<md-select [(ngModel)]="item.phase" name="item.phase">
    <md-option value="Phase1">Phase 1</md-option>
    <md-option value="Phase2">Phase 2</md-option>
    <md-option value="Phase3">Phase 3</md-option>
</md-select>
```

Am I missing something or is it a bug in material code library?

@angular/cli: 1.0.0
node: 7.4.0
os: darwin x64

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
  "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
  "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
  "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
  "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
  "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.1",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
  "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
  "angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.7",
  "core-js": "^2.4.1",
  "firebase": "^3.6.7",
  "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
  "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
  "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
  "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
  "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
  "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.26",
  "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
  "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-rc.0",
  "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
  "karma": "1.2.0",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
  "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
  "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
  "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
  "protractor": "~4.0.13",
  "ts-node": "1.2.1",
  "tslint": "^4.3.0",
  "typescript": "~2.0.3"
}
```

Comment: do you see any errors on console

Comment: No. Nothing there